# Improve scalpel and tagsoup performance

Tags: haskell, web-scraping

I have a scraper that selectively extracts links from HTML documents but it's very slow (about ten links per second on average web page).

The cost centres show that most time and allocations are spent in various functions of `Text.HTML.TagSoup.Implementation` module.

From user (my code) perspective it is this function using [scalpel](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scalpel-0.5.1/docs/Text-HTML-Scalpel.html#v:scrapeStringLike) that applies a predicate to pick only specific links:

```
scrapeHrefs :: (Ord content, Show content, StringLike content) => content -> Selector -> [content]
scrapeHrefs str s = (concat . maybeToList) $ scrapeStringLike str (chroots s (attr "href" anySelector))
```

My goal is to have >95% RTS productivity. This part of the program is at 30-50% and other parts are around 97% which (to me) is a starting point in order to compare with other languages.

Relevant settings:

```
ghc-options: -rtsopts -fprof-auto -fprof-cafs
command line: +RTS -p -RTS
```

Basic stats:

```
   9,075,850,544 bytes allocated in the heap
   3,828,726,032 bytes copied during GC
      78,951,768 bytes maximum residency (49 sample(s))
         933,008 bytes maximum slop
             222 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0      2137 colls,     0 par    2.636s   2.602s     0.0012s    0.0059s
  Gen  1        49 colls,     0 par    1.280s   1.463s     0.0299s    0.0591s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.002s elapsed)
  MUT     time    4.664s  ( 12.874s elapsed)
  GC      time    3.916s  (  4.065s elapsed)
  RP      time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  PROF    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  Total   time    8.580s  ( 16.942s elapsed)

  %GC     time      45.6%  (24.0% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    1,945,937,080 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  54.4% of total user, 76.0% of total elapsed
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you compiled/ran your code and how did you measure the performance, just to make sure you didn't fall for common mistakes. Also I see the type signature uses StringLike - if you use it with String you'll probably get an easy boost by switching to Text